# work with data grid view in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Dear sir,
   I m developing one application on c# windows forms by using OLEDB connection.On that one form i placed one datagridview and bind to one table.That table contains some fields....., here my problem is i want to edit table on runtime.On that table i need two links as edit,unmask.In runtime data in datagridview is seems to plain text on paper.if we click edit that row changed to text boxes and combo boxes.Sometext boxes contain passwords also.those are in ****** formate.while picking unmask button those passwords are changed to actual text.while picking edit button that exploted to update, cancel.Then we change the data and pick update then data stored to database table.(i need datagridview  as gridview in ASP.Net).Is there any properties for datagridview as gridview(ASP).Could you please suggest me how to resolve my prob.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you, at the time of the hang, hit pause in Visual Studio to see where your code hangs?

Comment: Where do you see in the question that his code hangs? I'm not saying it isn't there; I can't understand the question at all.